# A sophisticated Pythonic way to handle lists or arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to assign an integer value consecutively to successive same elements in a list. There should be no back coupling, i.e. same elements that appear later in the list should not have the same integer value as before.

Initial list:

```
x = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"]
```

Desired integer list:

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

My attempt:

```
idx = 0
int_list = list([idx])

for i in range(1, len(x)):
    if x[i] != x[i-1]:
        idx = idx + 1
    int_list.append(idx)
```

However, I think there's a more elegant way. Maybe even a two-liner.

Comment: `a` does not always become `1`?

Answer (score 4):

you can use itertools.groupby for this pretty easy

```
a= ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"]
b = []
for i,(key,group) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(a)):
    # key is the repeated value ... group is an iterator of all matches
    b.extend([i for _ in group])

print(b)
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

as pointed out by @jonclements in the comment we can reduce this to a single list comprehension

```
b = [i for i,(k,g) in enumerate(groupby(a)) for _ in g]
```

Comment: @Joran or as a basic list-comp: `b = [idx for idx, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(data)) for _ in g]`

Comment: that is indeed cleaner :)

Comment: very nice. I like it very. Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

Joran's answer is good for lists. If performance is important and you don't mind using NumPy, and you're dealing with numerical values or something that you can map to numerical values (e.g. `arr = list(map(ord, x))`), you can use this:

```py
>>> np.cumsum(np.diff(arr) != 0)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a rolling window using the zip function, and iterate through each pair of values and return True if they are not equal. The result is the cumulative sum of this array. I use NumPy's cumsum() but you can also write your own.

```
>>> list(np.cumsum([m!=n for m,n in zip([x[0]]+x[:-1], x)]))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```